# docker spark on docker zeppelin?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm new to docker 
kind of confused about the concept of docker container

I'm trying to use the below web-site's spark on zeppelin 
https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark

this web-site I download the zeppelin docker container
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dokFasXyQw&t=2s

now  I have this docker containers

```
1a8030d60105        bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.4-hadoop2.7   "/bin/bash /worker.sh"   13 days ago         Exited (137) 12 days ago    8081/tcp            spark-worker-1 <br/>
efbf74de4e87        bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7   "/bin/bash /master.sh"   13 days ago         Exited (137) 2 days ago                         spark-master <br/>

76fa0e88ad99        dylanmei/zeppelin:latest               "bin/zeppelin.sh"        2 weeks ago         Exited (143) 15 hours ago                       zeppelin <br/>
```

if I want this spark master or worker on the zeppelin image what should I do and which concept should I know? is there any good document or tutorial to do this?

I have been searching but I guess 'yarn' is the right one but not sure 
please give me the direction

Comment: Yes you can add the spark Interpreter  in Zeppelin with spark master url.

Comment: so do i have some how connect zeppelin container and spark container together? is my container concept is right? how about yarn?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your intention is to use zeppelin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dokFasXyQw&t=2s the zeppelin docker image comes with inbuilt spark . You dont have to start dockers from https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark . If You want to point to a different spark cluster then will need to change master configuration of zeppelin zeppelin-env.sh . If you define what you are trying to achieve that would help in getting a solution.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. just want to know that my idea above is a possible concept.

Comment: yes pointing zeppelin to different spark cluster is possible but if you just want to run spark code on zeppelin for learning/testing then you only need zeppelin nothing else